# Sql Server Query not getting desire Result

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want show record month wise and date wise. My query is this but I am not getting how I can achieve this.

**Query is**

```
   select 
     iWorkItemId
   , convert(varchar(20),Progress.dtProgressDate,106) as dtProgressDate
   , vsDescription
   , WPD.rWeightage
   , Progress.ProgressPerc as ProgressPerc
   , Convert(decimal(6,2)
   , ((WPD.rWeightage * Progress.ProgressPerc)/100)) as TotalProgress  
   from tblPkgWorkItems WPD 
   join tblPkgWorkItemsProgress Progress on WPD.iWorkItemId = Progress.iWorkItemsId  
   where iPackage='7' 
   group by iWorkItemId, dtProgressDate,vsDescription,rWeightage,ProgressPerc,progressmonth
   order by progressmonth ASC,dtProgressDate ASC , iWorkItemId ASC
```

Column name : (1) progressmonth  (Store Month Name)
              (2) dtProgressDate (Store complete date)

**Example :**

In our table we are storing the records like in this manner:

```
30 Apr 2013
31 Aug 2013
28 Feb 2013
30 Jan 2013
```

Then I want to show records like this

```
30 Jan 2014
if some record is inserted in 15 jan 2014 then After 30 jan 2014 then 15 jan 2014 record will show.

28 Feb 2014
30 Apr 2014
30 Aug 2014
```

Means firstly Jan records will come then Feb record then March records.

Means all records will come month by order then sort by date wise .

My data is being returned like this:

```
iWorkItemId dtProgressDate      progressmonth            rWeightage
320          30 Apr 2014                         Apr                       2
321         20 Apr 2014                      Apr                       3
320         10 Feb 2014                      Feb                       4
321         9 Jan 2014                       Jan                       7
```

I want record should come first 9 jan 2014 then 10 Feb 2014 (Means Order by Month) then after it  30 April 2014, then 20 april 2014 (Then Sot by Date).

iWorkItemId will repeat win every month.

For my problem is I want to show

Firstly Jan records then Feb records , then March records

**And whenever Jan month is coming then All Date which is belong to jan month that will come under JAN month.**

Firstly Higher date of JAN month (Means ) 31 Jan 2014, 30 jan 2014, 29 jan 2014, 28 feb  2014, then 27 feb 2014.

Means first records fetch month wise then on particular month that records sort by datewise

Comment: create a sqlfiddle.com link with your schema and sample data. It will be helpful

Comment: **Duplicate** of [Records come in month and date wise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306505/records-come-in-month-and-date-wise) - you **just** asked the same question not even an hour ago - please ***STOP*** posting the same question over and over and over again!

Comment: yes but some additional detail i have add in my query.

Comment: @Nitin In that case update your existing question.